# Memory error while merging datas with panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently facing a MemoryError with panda when I want to merge two data and I don't know why.

```
import pandas
import csv
import numpy as np

ListNames = ["dongsi","tiantan","guanyuan", "wanshouxigong","aotizhongxin","nongzhanguan","wanliu","beibuxinqu","zhiwuyuan","fengtaihuayuan","yungang","gucheng","fangshan","daxing","yizhuang","tongzhou","shunyi","pingchang","mentougou","pinggu","huairou","miyun","yanqin","dingling","badaling","miyunshuiku","donggaocun","yongledian","yufa","liulihe","qianmen","yongdingmennei","xizhimenbei","nansanhuan","dongsihuan"]

order_of_columns_extra = ['stationId','NO2','CO','SO2']

order_of_columns_aq_gp = ['stationId', 'utc_time', 'PM2.5', 'PM10', 'O3', 'temperature', 'pressure', 'humidity', 'wind_direction','wind_speed/kph']

order_of_columns_final = ['stationId', 'utc_time', 'PM2.5', 'PM10', 'O3', 'temperature', 'pressure', 'humidity', 'wind_direction','wind_speed/kph','NO2','CO','SO2']

for i in range(len(ListNames)):
    df_extra = pandas.read_csv(ListNames[i]+'_aq.csv', encoding='utf-8')
    df_aq_gp = pandas.read_csv('normal/'+ListNames[i]+'.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')

    df_Merged = pandas.merge(left = df_extra, right = df_aq_gp, how="left", left_on="stationId", right_on="stationId")

    df_Merged = df_Merged[order_of_columns_final]

    df_Merged.to_csv("WithExtra/"+str(ListNames[i])+".csv", index=False)
```

I have enough memory on my computer, so it's maybe not the problem
here's the fulle error given

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addExtra.py", line 18, in <module>
    df_Merged = pandas.merge(left = df_extra, right = df_aq_gp, how="left", left_on="stationId", right_on="stationId")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 58, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 596, in get_result
    concat_axis=0, copy=self.copy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 5203, in concatenate_block_managers
    concatenate_join_units(join_units, concat_axis, copy=copy),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 5332, in concatenate_join_units
    for ju in join_units]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 5332, in <listcomp>
    for ju in join_units]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 5632, in get_reindexed_values
    fill_value=fill_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 1379, in take_nd
    out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Maybe you do not have sufficient memory? We need a bit more information, e.g. how large your dataframes are in memory.

Comment: I have enough memory on my computer, the data that I want to merge are on 100'000 rows approximatively

Comment: Definitely looks like not enough memory. Try running a merge on a small subset of the dataframes and see if the merge succeeds.

Comment: add a print statement so as to know which iteration is it on, then check that file how many rows/column that file have.

If you're using unix like system also watch on top.

Comment: @harshil9968 I did the print and it look like this is the line that is the problem:  `df_Merged = pandas.merge(left = df_extra, right = df_aq_gp, how="left", left_on="stationId", right_on="stationId")`

Comment: line we know, that's also mentioned in the logs. But in the for loop for which file is it failing, did you see at ram usage using *top* command in terminal